# How to convert SQL into XML schema of one row per ID (FOR XML RAW)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have to convert SQL into an XML file using a schema that only makes one row per ID. The query converts an ID's "documents" and puts them all into a one row schema. Instead of making a new row for each document it should add additional documents to the existing ID row using the node "documentData"

Create and INSERT statements for test pop:

```
CREATE TABLE person  
(
birthDate varchar(255),
lastName varchar(255),
firstName varchar(255), 
externalStudentId3 varchar(255),
externalStudentId2 varchar(255),
externalStudentId1 varchar(255),
socialSecurityNumber varchar(255),  
documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate datetime, 
reason varchar(255),    
scopeValue varchar(255),     
documentScope varchar(255), 
status varchar(255),    
documentName varchar(255),  
externalDocumentId varchar(255),    
dateReviewed datetime,
dateReceived datetime,
dateCreated datetime,
documentRequirementExternalId varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO person
VALUES ('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999',NULL,NULL,NULL,'PERSON','UNSATISFIED','ApplicationUpdate','Application_Update','20190222','20190223','20190224','01309757'),
('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999','20190220','Document added to wrong year requirement.','2020','AwardYear','SATISFIED','CertOne','Cert_one','20190221','20190220','20190220','01294555')
```

Sample Data:

[excel screenshot of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJM70.png)

```
birthDate           lastName    firstName   externalStudentId3  externalStudentId2  externalStudentId1  socialSecurityNumber    documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate   reason                                      scopeValue  documentScope   status      documentName        externalDocumentId  dateReviewed                    dateReceived                    dateCreated                     documentRequirementExternalId
1954-03-09-05:00    Smith       Jon         100000166           3014925             3014925             999999999               NULL                                    NULL                                        NULL        PERSON          UNSATISFIED ApplicationUpdate   Application_Update  2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00   2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00   2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00   01-309757
1954-03-09-05:00    Smith       Jon         100000166           3014925             3014925             999999999               2019-02-20T10:54:08.670-05:00
```

Current Code that pulls multiple rows per ID:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT
          s.dateOfBirth as birthDate
          ,s.lastName
          ,s.firstName
          ,s.externalId3 as externalStudentId3
          ,s.externalId2 as externalStudentId2
          ,s.externalid1 as externalStudentId1
          ,s.socialSecurityNumber as socialSecurityNumber
          ,s.message as reason
          ,s.documentScopeCode as documentScope
          ,s.documentRequirementStatusCode as status
          ,s.name as documentName
          ,s.externalId as externalDocumentId
          ,s.revieweddate as dateReviewed
          ,s.receiveddate as dateReceived
          ,s.createddate as dateCreated
          ,s.documentRequirementExternalId as documentRequirementExternalId

FROM dbo.[person] s
FOR XML RAW ('student'), ROOT ('students');`
```

Current Output:

[current output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27VW0.png)

```
<persons>
<person birthDate="1954-03-09-05:00" lastName="Smith" firstName="Jon" externalStudentId3="100000166" 
externalStudentId2="3014925" externalStudentId1="3014925" socialSecurityNumber="999999999" 
documentScope="PERSON" status="UNSATISFIED" documentName="ApplicationUpdate" 
externalDocumentId="Application_Update" dateReceived="2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00" 
dateCreated="2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00" documentRequirementExternalId="01-309757" />
<person birthDate="1954-03-09-05:00" lastName="Smith" firstName="Jon" externalStudentId3="100000166" 
externalStudentId2="3014925" externalStudentId1="3014925" socialSecurityNumber="999999999" 
documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate="2019-02-20T10:54:08.670-05:00" reason="Document added to 
wrong year requirement." scopeValue="2020" documentScope="AwardYear" status="SATISFIED" 
documentName="CertOne" externalDocumentId="Cert_one" dateReviewed="2019-02-20T10:54:08.670-05:00" 
dateReceived="2019-02-19T13:35:03.143-05:00" dateCreated="2019-02-15T14:19:02.417-05:00" 
documentRequirementExternalId="01-294517" />
</person>
```

Desired Output:

[desired output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHcpE.png)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<persons>
  <person birthDate="1954-03-09-05:00" lastName="Smith" firstName="Jon" externalStudentId3="100000166" externalStudentId2="3014925" externalStudentId1="3014925" socialSecurityNumber="999999999"><documentData documentScope="PERSON" status="UNSATISFIED" documentName="ApplicationUpdate" externalDocumentId="Application_Update" dateReceived="2019-12-  05T08:40:17.737-05:00" dateCreated="2019-12-05T08:40:17.737-05:00" documentRequirementExternalId="01-309757" /><documentData documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate="2019-02-20T10:54:08.670-05:00" reason="Document added to  wrong year requirement." scopeValue="2020" documentScope="AwardYear" status="SATISFIED" documentName="CertOne" externalDocumentId="Cert_one" dateReviewed="2019-02-20T10:54:08.670-05:00" dateReceived="2019-02-19T13:35:03.143-05:00" dateCreated="2019-02-15T14:19:02.417-05:00" documentRequirementExternalId="01-294517" />
  </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Sample data will really help here. Showing us the result of your (failed) attempt doesn't help us; we don't know what it looks like *before*.

Comment: Also, the first XML data you provided isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I tried to add the sample data and gave a screenshot of it as well. This is essentiall what the data looks like that needs to be converted into a one row with additional nodes if there are multiple documents per ID. Let me know if there's something additional I can provide as well!

Comment: Your sample data only has one table; your query states there's 3

Comment: On a difficult note, why are you misusing the `NOLOCK` hint? It *will* give you wrong results: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @JasonH. It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible sample:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/creating-a-deep-hierarchy-with-for-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out. I used very few columns just to show the concept. You can easily extend it for your full solution.

> SQL

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.person;

CREATE TABLE dbo.person  
(
    birthDate varchar(255),
    lastName varchar(255),
    firstName varchar(255), 
    externalStudentId3 varchar(255),
    externalStudentId2 varchar(255),
    externalStudentId1 varchar(255),
    socialSecurityNumber varchar(255),  
    documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate datetime, 
    reason varchar(255),    
    scopeValue varchar(255),     
    documentScope varchar(255), 
    status varchar(255),    
    documentName varchar(255),  
    externalDocumentId varchar(255),    
    dateReviewed datetime,
    dateReceived datetime,
    dateCreated datetime,
    documentRequirementExternalId varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.person
VALUES ('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999',NULL,NULL,NULL,'PERSON','UNSATISFIED','ApplicationUpdate','Application_Update','20190222','20190223','20190224','01309757')
, ('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999','20190220','Document added to wrong year requirement.','2020','AwardYear','SATISFIED','CertOne','Cert_one','20190221','20190220','20190220','01294555');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    -- select columns pertaining to the person only
    SELECT DISTINCT externalStudentId3
        , firstName
        , lastName
    FROM dbo.person
)
SELECT p.externalStudentId3 AS [@id]
    , p.firstName AS [@firstName]
    , p.lastName AS [@lastName]
    , (SELECT c.externalStudentId3 AS [@id]
            ,c.documentScope AS [@documentScope]
            ,c.documentName AS [@documentName]
  FROM dbo.person AS c
  WHERE c.externalStudentId3 = p.externalStudentId3
  FOR XML PATH('documentData'), TYPE)
FROM rs AS p
FOR XML PATH('person'), ROOT('persons');
```

> Output

```
<persons>
  <person id="100000166" firstName="Jon" lastName="Smith">
    <documentData id="100000166" documentScope="PERSON" documentName="ApplicationUpdate" />
    <documentData id="100000166" documentScope="AwardYear" documentName="CertOne" />
  </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, your solution worked perfectly for what the output showed. However when I added the code it added spaces to not make it all in one line. The screenshot I attached showed it as one line but the original code output I pasted did not. I was able to edit it to show as one row now and hopefully it's just as easy of an edit for the code you provided to change it to one row instead. Thanks again!

Comment: Would it be possible to make a quick edit to your code to make it look like the new output? Thanks again for the help here!

Comment: Jason, XML is not a string. Also, it is inherently hierarchical. I shared the output how SSMS shows it.

Comment: Jason, you don't need to worry how XML is indented.

Comment: So from SQL to XML at least there's not a good way to make the one line per person ID? One of our systems uses this schema which is why i'm trying to find a decent way to be able to create it. Thank you for the continued help! Is there a way you'd recommend to look into that could do it?

Comment: Jason, as I already explained there is no difference between indented or not indented XML on the data level. Any presentation layer can show XML differently. You can save the produced XML as a file on the file system, and open it in any Internet browser: MS Edge, Firefox, Brave, etc.

Comment: oh ok, so it's just how it's being presented but should still work the same way. great! thank you for the continued explanation and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using FOX XML PATH. I can't test the code, some tweak may needed:

```
 CREATE TABLE person  
(
birthDate varchar(255),
lastName varchar(255),
firstName varchar(255), 
externalStudentId3 varchar(255),
externalStudentId2 varchar(255),
externalStudentId1 varchar(255),
socialSecurityNumber varchar(255),  
documentRequirementStatusChangeOnDate datetime, 
reason varchar(255),    
scopeValue varchar(255),     
documentScope varchar(255), 
status varchar(255),    
documentName varchar(255),  
externalDocumentId varchar(255),    
dateReviewed datetime,
dateReceived datetime,
dateCreated datetime,
documentRequirementExternalId varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO person
VALUES ('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999',NULL,NULL,NULL,'PERSON','UNSATISFIED','ApplicationUpdate','Application_Update','20190222','20190223','20190224','01309757'),
('19540309','Smith','Jon','100000166','3014925','3014925','999999999','20190220','Document added to wrong year requirement.','2020','AwardYear','SATISFIED','CertOne','Cert_one','20190221','20190220','20190220','01294555')


;WITH cte_person(birthDate,lastName,firstName,externalStudentId3,externalStudentId2,externalStudentId1,socialSecurityNumber)
AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    s.birthDate as birthDate
    ,s.lastName
    ,s.firstName
    ,s.externalStudentId3
    ,s.externalStudentId2
    ,s.externalStudentId1
    ,s.socialSecurityNumber as socialSecurityNumber
  FROM dbo.[person] s
)
SELECT
  s.birthDate as '@birthDate'
  ,s.lastName as '@lastName'
  ,s.firstName as '@firstName'
  ,s.externalStudentId3 as '@externalStudentId3'
  ,s.externalStudentId2 as '@externalStudentId2'
  ,s.externalStudentId1 as '@externalStudentId1'
  ,s.socialSecurityNumber as '@socialSecurityNumber',
  (SELECT
    d.documentScope as '@documentScope'
    ,d.reason as '@reason'
    ,d.status as '@status'
    ,d.documentName as '@documentName'
    ,d.externalDocumentId as '@externalDocumentId'
    ,d.dateReviewed as '@dateReviewed'
    ,d.dateReceived as '@dateReceived'
    ,d.dateCreated as '@dateCreated'
    ,d.documentRequirementExternalId as '@documentRequirementExternalId'
  FROM dbo.[person] d
  WHERE d.socialSecurityNumber=s.socialSecurityNumber
  FOR XML PATH ('documentData'), TYPE)
FROM cte_person s
FOR XML PATH ('student'), ROOT ('students');
```

Output:

```
<students>
  <student birthDate="19540309" lastName="Smith" firstName="Jon" externalStudentId3="100000166" externalStudentId2="3014925" externalStudentId1="3014925" socialSecurityNumber="999999999">
    <documentData documentScope="PERSON" status="UNSATISFIED" documentName="ApplicationUpdate" externalDocumentId="Application_Update" dateReviewed="2019-02-22T00:00:00" dateReceived="2019-02-23T00:00:00" dateCreated="2019-02-24T00:00:00" documentRequirementExternalId="01309757" />
    <documentData documentScope="AwardYear" reason="Document added to wrong year requirement." status="SATISFIED" documentName="CertOne" externalDocumentId="Cert_one" dateReviewed="2019-02-21T00:00:00" dateReceived="2019-02-20T00:00:00" dateCreated="2019-02-20T00:00:00" documentRequirementExternalId="01294555" />
  </student>
</students>
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter! This is super helpful and very close it seems. Here's the error I'm getting at the moment. I'm also going to try and add a CREATE and INSERT statement for additional ease to help.
Msg 422, Level 16, State 4, Line 28
Common table expression defined but not used.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: Updated to use the provided table/data